# getting no result but stuck in infinite loop in karatsuba algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, multiplication

**I am not getting any result my program stuck in infinite loop.**
I made a program for four values with same logic which worked great but with three values this is not working

```
def Karatsuba_Recursive(a, b):
    if not a or not b:
        return "0"
    if len(a) == 1 or len(b) == 1:
        return str(int(a)*int(b))
    else:
        m = max(len(a),len(b))
        m2 = m // 2
        A = a[0:-m2]
        B = a[-m2:len(a)].lstrip("0")
        C = b[0:-m2]
        D = b[-m2:len(b)].lstrip("0")
        val1 = int(Karatsuba_Recursive(A,C))
        val2 = int(Karatsuba_Recursive(B,D))
        val3 = int(Karatsuba_Recursive((str(A+B)),str((C+D))))
        return str((val1 * (10 **(2*m2))) + ((val3 - val1 - val2) * (10**(m2))) + val2)
```

Comment: What parameter values are you supplying in your test?

Comment: This code is very close, but for `val3` you need to add `A`  and `B` and then `C` and `D` as integers, not strings.  Also, you don't need the `lstrip`s, instead `A, B = a[:-m2], a[-m2:]` and `C, D = b[:-m2], b[-m2:]`, otherwise looks good!

Comment: I tested it for "77777","999"

Comment: Also, just checking, typically this function would accept numeric parameters `a` and `b` rather than string parameters. Were you required to support string parameters?

Comment: I wish you picked up [documenting](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#what-is-a-docstring) your code, if not helpful naming.

Comment: Yes string input is my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that `A+B` is a string concatenation, not numeric addition. This should be `int(A)+int(B)`. Same for `C+D`.

It is unfortunate that you select `m` to be `max(len(a),len(b))` as that makes it necessary to have that first `if not a or not b` test, and you would also need to adapt the above fix to work with empty strings.

You can avoid all that by taking `min(len(a),len(b))` for `m` instead.

Comment: Yes you are right about A+B . I will let you know if it solved